# Creating "m x n" Two Dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, linear-algebra

Would like to create a two dimensional `m x n` array in javascript, based on the number of columns, that is inputed as an argument in my function, the rows would be created from another argument which would be an array.

**What I look to achieve - Desired Result:**

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

function TwoDimensionalArray(numRows, numCols) {
//Magic happens here!
}

TwoDimensionalArray(arr, 4);
```

As you can see the is a 3 x 4 matrix below and a desired result

`[[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7],[8,9]]`

The input size doesn't make the difference, the number of columns is the key factor and the determinant factor.

**What I have currently - Not Desired Result:**

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

function TwoDimensionalArray(numRows, numColumns) {
   var twoD = [];

   for (var row = 0; row < numRows.length; ++row) {

     var cardIndex = numRows[row]

      // console.log(numRows[row]);

       var columns = [];

     for(var j =0; j < numColumns; ++j) {
        columns[j] = cardIndex;
    }

    twoD[cardIndex] = columns;
}

return twoD;
 };


var matrixTwoD = TwoDimensionalArray(arr, 4);

console.log(matrixTwoD);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][0]);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][1]);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][2]);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][3]);
```

My current code creates an array that repeats each of the elements 4 times each until the number 13 with a column size of 4: `[[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1]....[13,13,13,13]]`

Maybe am doing something wrong in my for loop or not approaching the problem correctly. But anything to point me in the right direction to get the above desire result.

**Bouns**

Also would anyone also be kinda to point me to additional resources for matrix algebra pertaining to this sort of problem and anything in general that would help for self study.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: A nice library: http://mathjs.org/index.html It offers matrices manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, slice the input *Array* into sections of `numCols` length

```
function TwoDimensionalArray(arr, numCols) {
    var arr2d = [],
        i;
    if (numCols) // safety first!
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += numCols)
            arr2d.push(arr.slice(i, i + numCols));

    return arr2d;
}
```

---

- `if (numCols)` prevents an infinite loop in the case *numCols* was not provided or is `0`
- `for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += numCols)` counts up from `0` in `numCols`, e.g. *`i = 0, 4, 8, 16, ...`* until we reach a number greater than `arr.length`
- [`arr.slice(i, i + numCols)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) creates a *sub-Array* of *Array* starting from (including) index `i` and ending at (excluding) index `i + numCols`, i.e. we get a `numCols` long *Array* starting with the item at index `i` of `arr`
- [`arr2d.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) appends a new item to the end of `arr2d`

Putting all these together, we can see that we are building a new *Array `arr2d`* from sections of the *Array `arr`*

Comment: Thank you! But could you elaborate more on the process in terms of why this solution? Just for learning purposes.  appreciate it :)

Comment: @Amechi I've added more detail in bullet points rather than comments, as I wasn't sure exactly which parts you wanted to know about

Answer (score 0):

calculate columns required and then use slice method of array.

**start index = (numColumns * i)**
**end index = numColumns * (i + 1)**

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

function TwoDimensionalArray(numRows, numColumns) {
  var columns = [];

  for (var i = 0; i !== Math.ceil(numRows.length / numColumns); i++) {
    columns[i] = numRows.slice((numColumns * i), numColumns * (i + 1))
      //console.log((numColumns * i) + " " +numColumns * (i + 1))
  }
  return columns;
};

var matrixTwoD = TwoDimensionalArray(arr, 4);

console.log(matrixTwoD);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][0]);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][1]);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][2]);
console.log(matrixTwoD[0][3]);
```